# How to add different background image for different methods of a class in Tkinter Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am trying to have different backgrounds for different pages of my program, but the problem is that only the window in the **init**() method has a background image.

```
class windows():
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen=Tk()
        self.font='Times New Roman'

        #size and initial position of the window
        self.screen.geometry("1100x700+200+50")

        #colour of screen
        self.canva= Canvas(self.screen, width= 1200, height= 800)
        self.canva.pack()
        self.img= ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("bg_main.png"))
        self.canva.create_image(0,0,anchor=NW,image=self.img)

        #self.canva.create_text(550,100,text="\tWELCOME TO \nQUESTION PAPER GENERATOR",font=(self.font,30,'bold'),fill='black')
        #fix window size 
        self.screen.maxsize(1100,700)
        self.screen.minsize(1100,700)

        #creating buttons
        self.add_ques=Button(self.screen,text="ADD QUESTIONS",fg="#02203d",font=(self.font,15,'bold'),bg="#fba75b",activebackground="#6d7a6d",command=lambda:self.add())
        self.add_ques.place(x=350,y=200,height=50,width=300)

        self.generate=Button(self.screen,text="GENERATE PAPER",fg="#02203d",font=(self.font,15,'bold'),bg="#fba75b",activebackground="#6d7a6d",command=lambda:self.generator())
        self.generate.place(x=350,y=310,height=50,width=300)

        self.add_ques=Button(self.screen,text="CREATE DATABASE",fg="#02203d",font=(self.font,15,'bold'),bg="#fba75b",activebackground="#6d7a6d",command=lambda:self.gen_database())
        self.add_ques.place(x=450,y=400,height=50,width=300)

        self.add_ques=Button(self.screen,text="ADD SUBJECTS",fg="#02203d",font=(self.font,15,'bold'),bg="#fba75b",activebackground="#6d7a6d",command=lambda:self.add_sub())
        self.add_ques.place(x=450,y=515,height=50,width=300)

    def add(self):
        self.screen.destroy()
        screen=Tk()

        #destuction function
        def destruction():
            screen.destroy()
            self.__init__()

        #size and initial position of the window
        screen.geometry("1100x700+200+50")


        #colour of screen
        bg = PhotoImage(file="bg.png")
        label_bgImage = Label(screen, image=bg)
        label_bgImage.place(x=0, y=0)
        #fix window size 
        screen.maxsize(1100,700)
        screen.minsize(1100,700)
```

In this, I want the `add()` method to have its own window with its own background. On running, it opens without an error, but no image is loaded.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function

Comment: where do you create other windows? Only main window should use `Tk()` and `mainloop()`. Other windows should use `Toplevel()` without `mainloop()`

Comment: using `self.__init__()` in other functions is wrong idea. If you have to run something from `__init__` then put it in separated function and run it in `__init__` and in `destruction()`

Comment: i did not knew about toplevel() , thanks @furas

Answer (score 1):

> how to add different background image for different methods of a class

The problem can be fixed. On `add()` function. You forgot to add `self.` to `self.img`

- On line 25, don't use lambda in command keyword `command=self.add`.
  Same as the other Button widgets.
- On line 39, add `self.screen.withdraw()`.
- On line 40, add `self.`  to screen.screen and renamed `Tk()` to
  `Toplevel()`.
- On line 49, `self.` to `self.screen.geometry`.
- On line 52, add `self.` to `self.img = ...`
- On line 53, add `self.` in `Label` widget parameter
  `Label(self.screen, image=bg)`
- On line 56 and 57 add `self.` to `self.screen`
- Online 60, add this `app = windows()`
- On line 61, add `mainloop()`

Snippet:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class windows():
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen = Tk()
        self.font='Times New Roman'

        #size and initial position of the window
        self.screen.geometry("1100x700+200+50")

        #colour of screen
        self.canva= Canvas(self.screen, width= 1200, height= 800)
         
        self.img= ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("p2.png"))
        self.canva.create_image(0,0,anchor=NW,image=self.img)
        self.canva.pack()

        #self.canva.create_text(550,100,text="\tWELCOME TO \nQUESTION PAPER GENERATOR",font=(self.font,30,'bold'),fill='black')
        #fix window size 
         

        #creating buttons
        self.add_ques=Button(self.screen,text="ADD QUESTIONS",fg="#02203d",font=(self.font,15,'bold'),bg="#fba75b",activebackground="#6d7a6d",command=self.add)
        self.add_ques.place(x=350,y=200,height=50,width=300)

        self.generate=Button(self.screen,text="GENERATE PAPER",fg="#02203d",font=(self.font,15,'bold'),bg="#fba75b",activebackground="#6d7a6d",command=lambda:self.generator())
        self.generate.place(x=350,y=310,height=50,width=300)

        self.add_ques=Button(self.screen,text="CREATE DATABASE",fg="#02203d",font=(self.font,15,'bold'),bg="#fba75b",activebackground="#6d7a6d",command=lambda:self.gen_database())
        self.add_ques.place(x=450,y=400,height=50,width=300)

        self.add_ques=Button(self.screen,text="ADD SUBJECTS",fg="#02203d",font=(self.font,15,'bold'),bg="#fba75b",activebackground="#6d7a6d",command=lambda:self.add_sub())
        self.add_ques.place(x=450,y=515,height=50,width=300)

    def add(self):
        #self.screen.destroy()
        self.screen.withdraw()
        self.top = Toplevel()
        self.top.title('New Window')
                     
       #destuction function
        def destruction():
            screen.destroy()
            self.__init__()
                  
         #size and initial position of the window
        self.top.geometry("1100x700+200+50")

         #colour of screen
        self.img = PhotoImage(file="p1.png")
        label_bgImage = Label(self.top, bg='red',image=self.img)
        label_bgImage.place(x=120, y=120)

        self.top.maxsize(1100,700)
        self.top.minsize(1100,700)
                  
        
app = windows() 
mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]